# python, pandas: How to specify multiple columns and merge only specific columns of duplicate rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

You can concatenate specific column values in a multi-column duplicate row by doing the following, but all columns other than those specified in the `groupby` will disappear.

The columns `title, thumbnail, name, created_at` are present.

Retrieve the rows with duplicate `title` and `thumbnail` as follows
and concatenate the values of the `name` column of the duplicated row while keeping the first row.
I want to create a new column for it.

However, as mentioned earlier, columns other than those specified in `groupby` will disappear.

```py
df.groupby(['title', 'thumbnail'])['name'].apply(lambda x: ' '.join(x)).reset_index()
```

Comment: Can you please provide some examples to make the question clearer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose the following dataframe:

```
>>> df
    title thumbnail   name   created_at
0  title1    thumb1  name1        today
1  title1    thumb1  name2    yesterday
2  title1    thumb2  name3  another day
```

The output of your code is:

```
>>> df.groupby(['title', 'thumbnail'], as_index=False)['name'] \
      .apply(' '.join)
    title thumbnail         name
0  title1    thumb1  name1 name2
1  title1    thumb2        name3
```

If you don't want to lost columns and rows (keep the shape), use `transform`:

```
df['name'] = df.groupby(['title', 'thumbnail'])['name'] \
               .transform(' '.join)
print(df)

# Output:
    title thumbnail         name   created_at
0  title1    thumb1  name1 name2        today
1  title1    thumb1  name1 name2    yesterday
2  title1    thumb2        name3  another day
```

Else you have to make a choice with other columns to keep them. In this case, do you want to keep 'today' or 'yesterday' for `created_at`? To do that, you can use `agg`:

```
>>> df.groupby(['title', 'thumbnail']) \
      .agg({'name': ' '.join, 'created_at': 'first'}) \
      .reset_index()

    title thumbnail         name   created_at
0  title1    thumb1  name1 name2        today
1  title1    thumb2        name3  another day
```

Setup:

```
data = {'title': ['title1', 'title1', 'title1'],
        'thumbnail': ['thumb1', 'thumb1', 'thumb2'],
        'name': ['name1', 'name2', 'name3'],
        'created_at': ['today', 'yesterday', 'another day']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Comment: Use `df.assign` if you don't want the assignment to be in-place.

Comment: I don't use `assign` for readability. I just want to illustrate only `groupby_apply`, `groupby_transform` and `groupby_agg`.

Comment: Replace `lambda x: ' '.join(x)` with `' '.join`

Comment: @rudolfovic. Good point! Thanks.

Comment: It's because you choose to keep the first row which is equivalent to `'first'`. You can use `transform` then `drop_duplicates` to get the same result (which is more clearer than your one line)

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

Using a toy `DataFrame` for illustration:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'title': ['tom', 'tom', 'tom', 'mark', 'mark', 'lewis'],
    'name': list('abcdef'),
    'marks': [55, 99, 14, 28, 19, 88]
})
```

In any case we will need to group:

```py
groups = df.groupby(['title', 'thumbnail'])
```

Here is a neat solution using a join:

```py
groups.first().join(groups['name'].agg(' '.join), rsuffix='s')
```

A more efficient solution would get the name aggregation and the rest of the columns in a single pass:

```py
def process(group):
  result = group.iloc[0] # take the first row
  # then add a concatenation of all names for this group
  result['schools'] = ' '.join(group['name'])
  # return the result data frame with a single row
  return result
```

This could also be done in a single line:

```py
def process(group):
  return group.iloc[[0]].assign(names=' '.join(group['name']))
```

Then simply apply the helper function to all the groups:

```py
groups.apply(process)
```

The two methods get the same results:

```py
       title   name  marks   names
name                             
lewis  lewis      f     88       f
mark    mark      d     28     d e
tom      tom      a     55   a b c
```

Answer (score 1):

That's because you're selecting the `name` column via `['']`, so by definition, the only columns available are going to be the columns that make up the index (which is required) and the column you're selecting.

Instead of calling `apply` on the `["name"]` column of the groupby, call `apply` directly on the groupby:

```py
df.groupby(['title', 'thumbnail']).apply(lambda x: ' '.join(x['name'])).reset_index()
```

Comment: this doesn't solve the problem of losing additional columns - have a look at my solution

Comment: @Corralien please explain exactly what you are getting and how